# ¿Como puedo convertir una imagen en un menu desplegable (ej icono de cocacola que se despliega)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<header>
  <ul><img src="img/chevrologo.png" class="menudesp">
    <li class="nosotros"><a>nosotros</a></li>
    <li class="auto"><a>autos</a></li>
    <li class="camioneta"><a>camionetas</a></li>
    <li class="submenu"><a>chevrolet</a>
      <ul href="registro.html"><a>registrate</a></ul>
      <ul href="ingresa.html"><a>ingresa</a></ul>
      <ul href="comercios.html"><a>comercios cercanos</a></ul>
      <ul href="historia.html"><a>historia</a></ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

**quiero hacer que esta lista se despliegue cuando me posiciono sobre la imagen chevrologo**

Comment: Puedes checar aqui haber si te es util, https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/es/articles/best-practices-for-responsive-dropdown-menus--cms-35212  ,  https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/how-to-make-the-bootstrap-navbar-dropdown-work-on-hover--cms-33840

Answer (score 0):

Buen día.

Aquí la respuesta utilizando el código que tienes en tú pregunta:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mostrar y Ocultar Lista</title>
    <style>
        #lista {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<script>
 
    function mostrar() {
        lista = document.getElementById("lista");
        lista.style.display = 'block';
      };
    
    function ocultar() {
        lista = document.getElementById("lista");
        lista.style.display = 'none';
    };
</script>
<body>
    <header>
        <ul><img onmouseover="mostrar()" onmouseout="ocultar()" src="img/chevrologo.png" class="menudesp">
            <ul id="lista">
                <li class="nosotros"><a>nosotros</a></li>
                <li class="auto"><a>autos</a></li>
                <li class="camioneta"><a>camionetas</a></li>
                <li class="submenu"><a>chevrolet</a>
                    <ul href="registro.html"><a>registrate</a></ul>
                    <ul href="ingresa.html"><a>ingresa</a></ul>
                    <ul href="comercios.html"><a>comercios cercanos</a></ul>
                    <ul href="historia.html"><a>historia</a></ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </header>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Como verás, utilice dos funciones en JS (mostrar y ocultar) las cuales se van a ejecutar cuando pases el ratón sobre la imagen (onmouseover) o lo quites (onmouseout), estas funciones van a cambiar el CSS relacionado con el ID llamado "lista" (código nuevo en tu pregunta) haciéndolo visible o no.

Recuerda comenzar con la lista (id) NO Visible en el CSS:

```
<style>
        #lista {
            display: none;
        }
</style>
```

NOTA: Te coloqué todo junto para que tuvieras el ejemplo completo, pero recuerda que como buena practica los JS y los CSS deben están en archivos aparte y ser referenciados (link).

Saludos y espero que te haya servido.

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* al menu le doy una altura de 0px y opacidad 0 para hacerlo invisible*/
.menuContent {
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(82, 82, 255);
    height: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* para cuando haga hover en la imagen mostrarlo */
.menudesp:hover + .menuContent{
    height: 150px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<header>
<!-- puse la img fuera del ul para poder desaparecer el contenido sin que se desapareciera la imagen-->
        <img src="img/chevrologo.png" class="menudesp">
        <ul class="menuContent">
            <li class="nosotros"><a>nosotros</a></li>
            <li class="auto"><a>autos</a></li>
            <li class="camioneta"><a>camionetas</a></li>
            <li class="submenu"><a>chevrolet</a>
            <!-- Aqui en vez de tener multiples <ul> debes poner un elemento padre ul y cada uno de los elementos de la lista debe ser un li (esto no tiene nada que ver con tu pregunta pero es bueno que lo sepas)  -->
                <ul>
                    <li href="registro.html"><a>registrate</a></li>
                    <li href="ingresa.html"><a>ingresa</a></li>
                    <li href="comercios.html"><a>comercios cercanos</a></li>
                    <li href="historia.html"><a>historia</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </header>
```